# Clear PrimeNg multiselect filter value programatically

Tags: angular, primeng

During a click event for performing some business process I need to clear the selected values (which I have done) and the filter value for PrimeNG multiselect.  I don't see a way to programmatically access the filter value of the multiselect, is this possible and if so how?  I would rather not use the `resetFilterOnHide` property.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this scenario?

Comment: @RN92 I have not, I'm still using v6 with ng6, it may be possible on later versions, I'm going to be looking into that for other issues, I'll update if I find an answer.

Comment: Same problem here. Need to find a way

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to clear the filter input value using onFilterShow / onFilterHide event, there is option called _filterValue of the element to set value as following:

**HTML:**

```
<p-multiSelect #element [options]=".data" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
        optionLabel="label" optionValue="label"
        [filter]="true" (onPanelShow)="onPanelShow(element)">
```

**TS:**

```
  onPanelShow(element: any) {
    element._filterValue = ''
  }
```

**Note:** PrimeNg V12.0 LTS

This may help you.